# Center button is scrollable table row

Tags: html, css, center, sticky

Table has columns, which overflow the table width. Thus table has horizontal scroll, and cells are scrolled horizontally.

Under some regular row with some number of cells, table has row with cell, which takes 100% width of the row, and contains a button 'Show more' .i.e.

```
<tr>
    <td colspan='100%'>
        <button>Show more</button>
    <td>
</tr>
```

Button should be centered (stick to center) on scroll. Also row has specific left border (`border: 2px solid yellow`), which also should not be scrolled (visually row with border, but technically - sticky cell with border)

How to make that button centered relatively to viewport? And not to use JS?
Now I have a working example with column `position: sticky and colspan='4'`, and button is centered inside that sticky cell. But it's not centered according to viewport.

```
<tr>
  <td class='sticky' colspan="4">
    <button>
      Show more
    </button>
  </td>
  <td class='red' colspan="100%"></td>
</tr>
```

[JSfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/umnx93b7/1/)

Comment: `position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; translate(-50%, -50%)` should center something on the viewport

Comment: this will take out the button from the document flow, and it can be taken out from the table on small screens